# Next 13 with app directory and Redux: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'apiSlice' before initialization

Tags: reactjs, next.js, redux-toolkit

Something tells me this is a cyclical dependency error but I can't seem to figure it out. The error happens on store.ts' line: `[apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer`

store.ts

```
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
    }
})
...
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>()
```

provider.tsx

```
"use client";

import { store } from "../store/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

export function Providers({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
}
```

admin-user.tsx

```
export function useAdminUser() { 
    const [getAdminUser] = useLazyGetAdminUserQuery()
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
    ....
}
```

layout.tsx

```
"use client";
import { Providers } from "../redux/provider";
export default function RootLayout({children}: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
        <body>
        <Providers>{children}</Providers>
        </body>
        </html>
    );
}
```

page.tsx

```
"use client"
import {useAdminUser} from "../../../hooks/admin-user";

export default function Page() {
    const app = useAdminUser()
    return <div>stuff</div>
}
```